# MYSQL Query to Select Max Value in a Column only from Current Date

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to run a query to select the maximum value from the 'MaxWind' column but only return the result from today's date.

You can probably see where I'm going here. I want the maximum windspeed for the current date. I would like to return what the value was and also the time it occurred.

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

This would work for "today":

```
select max(maxwind) from weather where stamp > '2015=10=16 0:00'
```

For each day, you could use CURDATE:

```
select max(maxwind) from weather where stamp >= CURDATE()
```